# Solving integral for Cauchy distribution density function

Tags: probability, integration, trigonometry

Reading a book about probability and statistics. During t and Cauchy distribution explanation author describe density function as $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi(1 + x^2)}dx$$ and he solves it as $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d \tan^{-1}(x)}{dx}$$
So my questions are :

1. What is $d \tan^{-1} x$?
2. How did author come to such solution?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \arctan(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$.

Comment: @Yuumita where did another dx disappear then?

Comment: I understand that arctan is indefinite integral of f(x) = 1/x^2. But usually we write integral as integral of f(x)dx. And if I take replace f(x) with its integral so it becomes g’(x), where does dx part disappear?

Comment: This seems to just be sloppy notation. It should just be $d\tan^{-1}(x)$ by the looks of it. (i.e. not divided by $dx$)

Comment: @ZoeAllen but at the end multiplied by dx? Where does dx disappear?

Comment: I think there should be a dx there. I think it's just sloppy notation, it hasn't actually disappeared.

Comment: The author should have written either $\displaystyle \int \frac{d\tan^{-1}(x)}{dx}\,dx$ or simply $\displaystyle \int d\tan^{-1}(x)$. The two integrands are equivalent, since we have the differential $d\tan^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{d\tan^{-1}(x)}{dx}\,dx$ by the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

It is very sloppy notation.

A more accurate represenation of that integral would be $$\frac {1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac {dx}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: what you showed is form which comes before form Ive mentioned(In the book)